# Cache control / max age not working for my site

Tags: cache

In order to speed up my site [Telium](http://www.telium.ca) I implemented all of the .htaccess recommendations from this [site](http://samaxes.com/2011/05/improving-web-performance-with-apache-and-htaccess/).  However, when I browse to my web site  with the developer tools open (in Chrome), I see that all of the images on my pages are being re-downloaded every time I refresh.  Strangely, the headers look right - so why are the images not being cached?

My .htaccess is located in the root of the web site, and looks like this:

```
# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype font/opentype
</ifModule>
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(js)$">
# was private  
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

Comment: Have you checked your Apache installation that it contains these modules?

Comment: It's a commercially hosted (GoDaddy)...BUT..when I look at header of the images files retrieved they DO say max-age a year out etc...do you see something wrong in the response headers?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "refreshing the page", try going to another page and clicking a link to go to the page, or copy the link into a new tab, and press enter.

What I have found is that when you click "refresh" Chrome assumes the user thinks something is out of date, and so it purposefully ignores the cache and downloads things fresh.